# Service Fabric Reverse Proxy with SignalR negotiate

Tags: signalr, reverse-proxy, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I am hitting the reverse proxy url for my stateful service to connect to a SignalR hub, and when SignalR attempts to establish a connection the javascript client calls the negotiate endpoint, which returns a url parameter that it then attempts to use for the connect endpoint. The issue is that the url parameter returned is the partial route to the endpoint listener exposed on the cluster. 
    http://localhost:19081/MyServiceFabiricApplication/MyStateFulService/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1&PartitionKey=1&PartitionKind=Int64Range

which returns succesfuly with

```
{"Url":"/9fd06df9-4399-4ea8-8771-9875b6ee4026/132235137104318266/8d308cc3-2fd7-40a6-96c3-2e521bf384ef/signalr",...
```

How can I tell signalR to disregard the URL returned from negotiate and to use the reverse proxy url that I initially provided it to connect? The problem ultimately is it mixes the returned route with the reverse proxy url I originally provided, so the connect attempt to use a fankenstein url with the port of the reverse proxy but the route of the fabric node. This results in 404.

```
ws://localhost:19081/9fd06df9-4399-4ea8-8771-9875b6ee4026/132235137104318266/8d308cc3-2fd7-40a6-96c3-2e521bf384ef/signalr/connect
```

This is because the route returned from the negotiate endpoint would have to be called directly though the exposed port of my endpoint, which is 5102.

```
   ws://localhost:5102/9fd06df9-4399-4ea8-8771-9875b6ee4026/132235137104318266/8d308cc3-2fd7-40a6-96c3-2e521bf384ef/signalr/connect
```

Somehow I need to fix the url before it tries to connect because the one it generates from negotiate is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an ajax data filter to intercept the negotiate response and rewrite the url back to the reverse proxy

```
   jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  dataFilter: (data, type) => {
    //modify the data
    if (~data.indexOf('ConnectionToken') && ~data.indexOf('Url') & ~data.indexOf('TryWebSockets')) {
      var dataobj = JSON.parse(data);
      dataobj.Url = this.ServiceProxyUrl + "signalr";
      return JSON.stringify(dataobj);
    }
    return data;
  }
});
```